# Which RAID10-like option would make the most sense for a Hyper-V VM to ensure recovery of any 1 drive?

Tags: virtual-machine, raid, hyper-v

I have 4 hard drives that I want to use for storage for a Hyper-V VM (A Windows Server 2016 Standard VM running on a Windows Server 2016 Standard Host). Assuming the drives are 4 TB each, I would like to have 8 TB continous space available to the VM, and a mirror of those. (This is a data-drive, the OS drive is independent and not relevant here)

The goal is that I can recover data from any of those drives, so in a worst-case scenario where 3 of the 4 drives are completely dead, I want to be able to get at least the 4 TB data from the remaining drives instead of a total loss.

I think that the common option (before drives got large) here would be a RAID10, so that I have the continous space of RAID-0 and the full mirror of RAID-1. But I wonder if there is a better option available since I have Windows Storage Spaces available, and since the consumer is a VM - the host doesn't have to see 8 TB continuous space, only the VM.

In essence, I wonder if there is a better option, like:

- Have 2 independent VHDX files that just somehow transparently form a single NTFS partition on the actual VM, but can be independently mounted for data recovery
- Or maybe expose the disk to the VM via iSCSI instead of attaching a VHDX (as said, it's not the Boot/OS drive, just a data drive).
- Or attach both VHDX files and use the Computer Management on the VM to create a stripe.
- Use some sort of Distributed or Cluster Filesystem instead of regular NTFS (on the VM) and ReFS (on the Host)?

Any suggestions on the sanest, easiest to maintain, least headache-inducing approach for this?

[image: Diagram of the Setup]

Comment: RAID10 isn't going to give you anything if only one of four drives survives. I think you're looking for "_magic_". Why won't two mirrors work?

Comment: @Attie Yeah, RAID10 by itself wouldn't work reliably. Two mirrors means  that the VM sees 2x4 TB, which are two separate "things" instead of 1 big thing that I can just copy data into without having to think about distributing it. I guess I'm hoping that Windows or ReFS or Hyper-V has some magic built-in as they have the benefit of understanding what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe it is realistically possible given your setup. The first and best solution is to get bigger drives. Anything else and you have a high chance of not being able to recover what you want to recover if you have to recover.

First, we have to question your 8TB contiguous VHDX: Unless you have a **compelling** reason to do this, don't do this. And that compelling reason has to bey VERY compelling.

Next, the only way you'd be able to keep data in order would be to use a mirror array. But the fact that your "data" is twice as large as any individual drive means that, be definition, you cannot use a mirror array.

You CAN set up arrays that have higher levels of fault tolerance. In fact, a RAID 6, given your particular configuration, offers few performance increases, but does allow for loss of any two drives in the array while offering 8TB (and only 8TB) of storage.

Comment: Three-way mirroring in Storage Spaces could tolerate 2 disk failures in a 5 (minimum number) disk array.